# Gitversion version bump message doesn't work

Tags: git, semantic-versioning, gitversion

I have following GiVersion.yml:

```yml
next-version: 1

mode: ContinuousDelivery

assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch

increment: Inherit

major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'

minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'

patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'

branches: {}

ignore:

  sha: []

merge-message-formats: {}
```

I need to increment version with a commit message that contains "+semver: patch" etc. And it works **but** only for the first time.

So I have next behaviour. My initial version is 1.0.0 . I made some changes and commit them with "... +semver: patch". Now my version is 1.0.1 .
Ok. Let's try it one more time. Some changes -> commit with "+semver: patch". And version is still 1.0.1

Now I'm trying to increase minor version. Same workflow: Some changes -> commit with "+semver: minor". If I check recent version I will get 1.1.0 . But! If I try to increase minor version one more time I doesn't work as well as patch.

And I have the same story with major.

I am new here, so does anybody know what wrong with that?

Comment: So, maybe this is intended behavior. I'm having the issue but apparently, one is supposed to 'release' on every version change. That means, after you have your 1.0.1, you have to create a tag with that version. Then the next patch will be 1.0.2. I'm been playing around with and so it seems the bump message is only for 1 increase since the last tag.